# Using script[.bat] to Check overdue files with file extention

Tags: batch-file

I am new in writing scripts. I need helps in writing a script which i will describe in details as below:

1. Currently, I have 4 folders:

   - 2 folders with .pdf
   - 2 folders with .rar file
2. One script file. To check all of the folders.
3. This script is to search by extension (.pdf/.rar) and check the file's date if it is overdue (like overdue 1 day).
4. Alert by sending email base on the file's folder name which contains overdue files to PIC.

Comment: since i am new, what i have try is move a file from one folder to another folder, thats all

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the FORFILES command. (Type FORFILES /? for documentation)

```
:: Set this Variable to the command to email someone
SET MAILER=echo mail user -s
:: Set this variable to the number of days overdue to look for
SET OVERDUE=1
:: Set folder names here - these are relative to the current directory
SET FOLDERS= "C:\temp\BLANK" "C:\TEMP\New Folder" 
:: Now loop through the folders
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d %FOLDERS%') do (
   echo %%G
   FORFILES /p "%%G" /s /d %OVERDUE% /c "cmd /c %MAILER% @file"
   PAUSE
   )
 EXIT /b
```